# Is there any helpline provided by Google to the users of Gmail account

Tags: gmail

Actually, I am just another Gmail account users and I am facing some issues with my Gmail account, that's why i am looking for some helpline or help forum or any other medium to resolve my issues provided by Google to users 
so please let me know if you have any information regarding that.

Comment: If you want *us* to help with your problem then you need to properly ask it on [webapps.se] giving all of the details. If your problem is with a desktop email client interacting with Gmail then you can ask your question here.

Answer (score 1):

[Gmail Help Center](https://support.google.com/mail/?hl=en#topic=3394144) is the official site for google support